# can't declare fstream object? but can declare it as a pointer?

Tags: c++, ifstream

been banging my head on the table over this all night.

I'm simply trying to declare an ifstream object like so....

```
ifstream inputStream;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error 5 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "public: char const & __thiscall std::_String_const_iterator<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::operator*(void)const " (??D?$_String_const_iterator@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEABDXZ)    C:\Users\Julz\Desktop\My Dropbox\3rdYear\2ndSemester\Games Prog\Game\DemocracyInvaders\Score.obj    DemocracyInvaders
```

I can declare it as a pointer like so...

```
ifstream *inputStream;
```

but that just goes on to headaches when I try to read in file data and I figure I should work out why the basic declaration isn't working before trying some hacked out fix.

I'm using SDL and have the following includes in a header a few files down...

```
#ifndef SDL_GRAPHICS_H //just a class I'm using to initialise my SDL stuff
#define SDL_GRAPHICS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include "SDL.h" 
#include "SDL_ttf.h"
```

I've tried swapping the SDL includes above the C++ stuff and all sorts of variations, nothing.
My header includes are all in the right order and I'm thinking that if there was a problem with includes I couldn't declare the ifstream as a pointer?

oh, I've tried using fstream and even just declaring ofstream, all the same error.
also, it doesn't matter what class (source or header) I try it in, always the same. Even tried declaring it in my driver (main) file with the includes directly in it, no dice...
Totally lost here!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are failing to link the C runtime into your application.  When declared as a non-pointer you bring in at least the constructor of the `ifstream` class into your application.  It appears that the constructor calls a function which is a part of the C-runtime and hence you end up with a linking error.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx

Comment: Or failing to link the _correct_ CRT. `__imp___CrtDbgReportW` looks like something that's specific to the Debug CRT.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. I had the wrong threading (thing) set in the runtime library. I just had it set to the lazy foo suggested setting for using SDL, I just set it to inherit from parent (or some such option) and Robert's your aunties live in lover!!